# Woocommerce product image is not show on facebook

Tags: wordpress

When i share my woocommerce product on facebook or other social platform the product image is not show. Please help someone to solve this issue.

Comment: Make sure "og:image" meta tag is present on your product page

Answer (score 0):

Go to Facebook Debugger and click Scrape like two times, you must be logged in with the fb of this website. Search Facebook debugger tutorials to see how it works.